# Can I use the same table to represent different Entities in Symfony?

Tags: php, doctrine

I am migrating an old PHP project to Symfony. I am trying to create the entities based on the existing database schema which I **can not change**. I am facing a problem :

There is a table that would represent two different entities. Basically, there is a boolean (a `tinyint(1)`), if the boolean is false, then the row of the table is representing a cart. If the boolean is true, then the row is representing an order.

Is it possible for Doctrine to make the distinction between these and to fetch those entities accordingly ? The solution I was willing to implement was creating several entities and overwrite the `find()` and `findAll()` methods in these entities' repositories. Is there another way to achieve that ?

Comment: You could give [inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) a try.  Never seen a boolean used as the discriminator column but it might work.  Have fun with your schema.  If it has this sort of stuff in it then who knows what else you might encounter.

Comment: @Cerad I don't thing your comment is correct. This is a perfectly reasonable schema. Nothing wrong about using boolean as a discriminator value. Plus, an ``order`` entity may not have any difference with a ``cart`` entity. There is no reason to have one more table here !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what doctrine call [Inheritance Mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

So you'll have one `Cart` entity and one `Order` entity extended it.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CartRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType(value="SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="is_order", columnDefinition="BOOL DEFAULT FALSE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap(
 *     value={
 *      CART::IS_CART=Cart::class,
 *      CART::IS_ORDER=Order::class
 *     }
 * )
 */
class Cart {
   const IS_CART = FALSE;
   const IS_ORDER = TRUE;
   ... // Entity field, getters, setters, functions...
}
```

Then your `Order` Entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=OrderRepository::class)
 */
class Order extends Cart {...}
```

There is maybe some mistake in this code I didn't test it but it should be ok.